# Show Div if any one option from all radios selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are many answers on stake over flow on this thread but they didn't solve my problem what i want to do is i have 4 radios with same name same id i want to when i select any of them it show me a div  but it works on just first radio when i select it don't work on 2nd , 3rd,  4th,

```
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb" onchange="show_input()"  />
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb" onchange="show_input()" />
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb" onchange="show_input()"/>
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb" onchange="show_input()" />
```

this j query function i'm using...

```
function show_input(){
 if($('#roof_types').is(':checked'))
    $(".measurement").fadeIn(300);
}
```

Not working on fiddle by working with same code on my browser 
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadsaadkhan/x1kn7p8q/

Comment: id should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more possibilities how to achieve that, one of them is to define `show_input` function

```
function show_input() {
    return $('#showdiv').show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1kn7p8q/4/

Without the function, directly on the radio event:

```
$('.rad_roof').change(function() {
    $('#showdiv').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1kn7p8q/5/

See that in both examples I avoided using `#fb` which has to be unique. If you use `#fb` in JS, it will work with the first one `#fb` only, attr id on other elements will be ignored.

Try this and click on any radio, alert will be shown only if you click the first one.

```
$('#fb').click(function() {
    alert('#fb clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1kn7p8q/7/

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect markup. IDs should be unique.

The main issue is you have incorrect selector to target the checked radio button. use:

```
 if($('.rad_roof:checked').length) $("#showdiv").show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qswdzpnm/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rad_roof').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(".showdiv").show();
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.rad_roof').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.measurement).fadeIn(300);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page must contain unique ids and you have give duplicate for all you inputs and you have not define javascript method which you are calling on you onchange event in html. Try this code:

you Html Code:

```
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb1" />
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb2" />
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb3" />
<input class="rad_roof" type="radio" name="fb" id="fb4" />
<div class="showdiv" id="showdiv">
     <h2>Facebook</h2> 
    <br />
    <input class="fb" type="text" name="fb" placeholder="Facebook" />
</div>
```

Your JS

```
$('.rad_roof').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) $("#showdiv").show();
});
```